# How to find out the URL of an image using Firebug or Chrome DevTools?

Tags: firebug

I'm not able to find out the logo image URL (the tree in the circle saying) in this page:

http://www.woodstock.ac.in/

I've used both Firebug (which I use regularly) and also Chrome's DevTools, which point to text in which I can't find the logo's URL.

I'd like to know where it is hidden and how to locate it using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the Logo hasnt been inserted seperatly in the website and it is added as a background-image property in the css p Tag!.
background-image:url(/uploaded/images/home/hometb_bg.png);

http://www.woodstock.ac.in/uploaded/images/home/hometb_bg.png

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome you can right click on the page you have the the tab:

```
 - RESOURCES
```

and inside you have the directory:

```
 - Frames
   - www.woodstock.ac.in
   - images
```

inside images you find all images used by the website. I see also see the logo.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the URL of the image using Firebug you have two options:

1. **Inspect the HTML and CSS**
   When inspecting the HTML structure you need to know that the image can be referred to in two ways: Either within the HTML structure itself via the `<img>` tag or within the CSS applying to the element (shown in the [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel)), normally via the `background` or `background-image` property.
   To get the element, which has the image, do the following steps:

   1. Right-click the image on the page and choose *Inspect Element with Firebug* from the context menu
   2. Check whether the image is referenced within the HTML or the CSS related to the element.
   3. If not, delete the element by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> on right-clicking the element within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) and choosing *Delete Element* from the context menu and repeat from step 1.
      In the end you'll see that the image is applied to the table with the id `#topbanner` via the CSS `background-image` property. To copy the URL, right-click it and choose *Copy Image Location* from the context menu.
2. **Inspect the network requests**
   You can check the network requests for the image using the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel). Therefore you need to follow these steps:

   1. Activate the panel
   2. Reload the page
   3. Select the *Images* filter to ensure to just see the transfered images
   4. Hover each image request to see a preview of the image
      You'll find the request for the image saying "GET homepg_bg.png". To copy the URL, right-click the request and choose *Copy Location* from the context menu.

In other developer tools these steps work similar.